# PHP addslashes using array

Tags: php

I am attempting to update multiple records using one form, but have run into a problem in attempting to use the **`addslashes`** function.

The form looks like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="editnewscategorysubmit.php">
<table width="405">
<tr>
<td width="246"><span class="link1">News Category </span></td>
<td width="146" colspan="2"><span class="link1">Delete?</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='title[]' value='$title' style='width:700px;'>
<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$id'>
</td>
<td>
<div style='padding-left:8px;'><a onclick='return confirmSubmit()' href='deletenewscategory.php?id=$id'><img src='images/delete.jpg' border='0'></a></div>
</td>
</tr>                               
<tr>
<td><input name="image" type="image" src="images/submit.png" alt="Submit Form" border="0" /></td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The PHP code that processes this looks like this:

```
$identity = $_REQUEST['id'];
$title = addslashes($_REQUEST['title']);
include 'connection.php';
for($i=0;$i<count($identity);$i++)
{
$query = "update newscategory set title = '$title[$i]' where id = '$identity[$i]'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Success. The news categories were updated.";
include 'return.php';
```

The warning that is returned is:

> Warning: addslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/u180175506/public_html/editnewscategorysubmit.php on line 71

What I am trying to do is to addslashes (or from what I'm reading, using **`mysql_real_escape_string`** is preferred!) to each value prior to updating the table. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions any more, they were replaced 10 years ago...

Comment: I'm fine with you using mysql_ functions (provided you are aware of the caveats) but using addslashes() to escape query parameters is a really, REALLY bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to run some function over an array. A simple loop:

```
$stillNotSafeData = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $stillNotSafeData[$key] = addslashes($value);
    } else {
        foreach ($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
            $stillNotSafeData[$key][$innerKey] = addslashes($innerValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Or using `array_walk_recursive`:

```
array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, function(&$item, $key) {
    $item = addslashes($item);
});
```

But as you already note you should not use `addslashes` for this. However once you have a valid connection to mysql using the `mysql_*` functions you can do the same thing using [`mres`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

But you neither should do that. The `mysql_*` functions has been officailly deprecated for some time now (and will be removed in less than a year from the language core).

Besides the fact it will be removed soon there are also some "edge" cases which get around it: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Long story short: stop using the mysql_* functions.

What you really want to do is use either `mysqli` or `PDO`. These support prepared statements and bound parameters. This post will help you with this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: +1 for the array_walk_recursive solution. Works fine. I use it for the $_POST and $_GET variable when magic quotes are disabled on the server.

Comment: magic quotes? in 2019? Please don't use magic quotes and definitely don't try to emulate it. It should have never been a thing. Escape/encode/sanitize your data properly for the specific context you are using it in.

Comment: The context is old software.

Answer (score 10):

Function:

```
function addslashes_recursive( $data )
{
    if ( is_array( $data ) )
    {
        return array_map( 'addslashes', $data );
    }
    else
    {
        return addslashes( $data );
    }
}
```

Single line

```
$array = array_map( 'addslashes', $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map('addslashes', $_REQUEST['title']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Ofcourse there are other ways to apply function to each array element. You can foreach() it, and apply addslashes() to each value, or assign $var to addslashes($title[$i]) in your for loop.