# Escaping a string with quotes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I would like to insert the content of an excel file into my database.
I simply use a raw query to achieve this.

---

**The controller function**

```
public function uploadExcel()
{
    $filename = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();

    $file = fopen($filename, "r");

    $count = 0;
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $count++;

        if($count>1) {
            DB::statement("INSERT INTO `members` (
                member_title,
                member_first_name,
                member_name_affix,
                member_last_name,
                member_private_address,
                member_private_zip_code,
                member_private_location,
                member_private_phone,
                member_private_mobile,
                member_private_fax,
                member_private_mail,
                member_business_position,
                member_business_name,
                member_business_address,
                member_business_zip_code,
                member_business_location,
                member_business_area_code,
                member_business_phone,
                member_business_fax,
                member_business_mobile,
                member_business_mail,
                member_join_date,
                extra
            ) VALUES (
                '$emapData[0]',
                '$emapData[1]',
                '$emapData[2]',
                '$emapData[3]',
                '$emapData[4]',
                '$emapData[5]',
                '$emapData[6]',
                '$emapData[7]',
                '$emapData[8]',
                '$emapData[9]',
                '$emapData[10]',
                '$emapData[11]',
                '$emapData[12]',
                '$emapData[13]',
                '$emapData[14]',
                '$emapData[15]',
                '$emapData[16]',
                '$emapData[17]',
                '$emapData[18]',
                '$emapData[19]',
                '$emapData[20]',
                '$emapData[21]',
                '$emapData[22]'
            )");
        }
    }
    return redirect('index.index');
}
```

---

**My Problem:** There are names in the excel file like Mc'Neal, so I get an error message. 

**How can I escape the apostrophe in laravel??** 

I am really new to laravel and would be happy for any kind of help!

Comment: Why don't you populate a `member` model and save()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried `addslashes()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: No! Thank you!! However, I have to pass a string to that function and $emapData is an array..

Comment: try something like `array_map( "escapeFunction" ,$emapData)` ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210833/php-addslashes-using-array

Comment: This is NOT the best approach.  The page you link to specifically says:

"The addslashes() is sometimes incorrectly used to try to prevent SQL Injection. Instead, database-specific escaping functions and/or prepared statements should be used."

What you likely want is:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Addslashes is not suitable for escaping database content, as @ShaneMit indicates.

Answer (score 2):

**To escape strings with single quotes for MS SQL, we would need to escape it by adding an another single quote.**

The following function does this. So, you may try using this function:

```
public static function mssql_escape($unsafe_str) 
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $unsafe_str = stripslashes($unsafe_str);
    }
    return $escaped_str = str_replace("'", "''", $unsafe_str);
}
//for example $unsafe = "AB'CD'EF";
$escaped = mssql_escape($unsafe);
echo $escaped;// Would output the escaped string as  "AB''CD''EF"
```